# Element repeats a lot of times when the view renders

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, pug

I'm making a controller for show a user profile page, in this page we can view the user projects and a button for follow that user. When i render the view on Jade, the button is displayed a lot of times. I think this happens with a loop of `Project.find()`

This is what i have on the **controller**.

```
userShow : function(req, res){
      Account.findOne({ username: req.params.username }, function(err, userWatch){
        Follow.findOne({followingUserID : userWatch.id}, function(err, follows){
          Project.find({ProjectOwner : userWatch.id}, function(err, projects){
            res.render('account/profile',{
              title : userWatch.username,
              user : req.user,
              watchUser : userWatch,
              listProjects : projects,
              listFollows : follows
            });
          });
        });
      });
    },
```

And the content from the **view**.

```
extends ../includes/layout

block content
  div(class="wrap")
    include ../includes/header
    div(class="ink-grid")
      div(class="column-group vertical-space")
        div(class="all-100")
          - console.log("console.log en vistas y listFollows: "+ listFollows);
          - console.log("console.log en vistas y listProjects"+ listProjects);
          h1 #{title}
          if(user)
            for follow in listFollows
              form(method="post" action="/follows/#{watchUser.id}")
                button(type="submit" class="ink-button green") follow
        div(class="all-100")
          div(class="all-50")
            h3 #{watchUser.username}
            p #{watchUser.emailAccount}
          div(class="all-50")
            button(class="ink-button grey") send message
        div(class="all-100")          
          div(class="all-100")
            div(class="all-80")
              for project in listProjects
                div(class="all-25")
                  figure(class="ink-image bottom-space") 
                    figcaption(class="over-top dark")
                      p #{project.ProjectName} 
                    img(src="/userFiles/projectImage/#{project.ProjectFileName}")

    div(class="push") 
  include ../includes/footer
```

Content from **console.log**.

```
console.log en vistas y listFollows: 

    { __v: 0,
      alreadyFav: true,
      followingUserID: '5720977ffe0697f51001c9a1',
      fromFollowUserId: '5720977ffe0697f51001c9a1',
      createdAt: Sat May 21 2016 19:23:43 GMT+0300 (+03),
      updatedAt: Sat May 21 2016 19:23:43 GMT+0300 (+03),
      _id: 57408b8fdecb09cb1a2a8b11 }
    console.log en vistas y listProjects{ __v: 0,
      ProjectLocation: 'Barcelona',
      ProjectAmount: 5555555,
      ProjectFileName: 'UploadedOn1462972254926fileOrigName13173780_1079858715421616_6060943026998765865_n.jpg',
      ProjectDetails: 'Proyecto de prueba, usuario testauth5',
      ProjectName: 'Proyecto 1',
      ProjectOwner: '5720977ffe0697f51001c9a1',
      _id: 57332f5fb4b04c3417fd32d7 },{ __v: 0,
      ProjectLocation: 'Lugar fántastico',
      ProjectAmount: 777777,
      ProjectFileName: 'UploadedOn1462977655765fileOrigNamerapunzel__s_tower_2_by_rosequartz-d3f7i0u.jpg',
      ProjectDetails: 'Loft acojedor con interior de madera. Perfecto para la clausura o encerrar a alguien.',
      ProjectName: 'Torre de Rapunzel',
      ProjectOwner: '5720977ffe0697f51001c9a1',
      _id: 57334477b4b04c3417fd32d8 },{ __v: 0,
      ProjectLocation: 'Lugar fantástico',
      ProjectAmount: 900000,
      ProjectFileName: 'UploadedOn1462979462355fileOrigNametumblr_mi43enfyLB1qcbsgdo1_500.jpg',
      ProjectDetails: 'económico castillito de piedra y tejado de pizarra ',
      ProjectName: 'Castillo de teja negra',
      ProjectOwner: '5720977ffe0697f51001c9a1',
      _id: 57334b86b4b04c3417fd32d9 },{ __v: 0,
      ProjectLocation: 'Suiza',
      ProjectAmount: 666666,
      ProjectFileName: 'UploadedOn1463581840556fileOrigName13122913_798137460320744_2366020950260825105_o.jpg',
      ProjectDetails: 'texto de prueba en proyecto 20',
      ProjectName: 'proyecto 20',
      ProjectOwner: '5720977ffe0697f51001c9a1',
      createdAt: Wed May 18 2016 17:30:40 GMT+0300 (+03),
      updatedAt: Wed May 18 2016 17:30:40 GMT+0300 (+03),
      _id: 573c7c903f4b91120feecf93 },{ __v: 0,
      ProjectLocation: 'Viena',
      ProjectAmount: 2222222,
      ProjectFileName: 'UploadedOn1463751212107fileOrigName8e03d5919704bfa20f45a94e207d5025.600x.jpg',
      ProjectDetails: 'otro castillito de ejemplo',
      ProjectName: 'little castle',
      ProjectOwner: '5720977ffe0697f51001c9a1',
      createdAt: Fri May 20 2016 16:33:32 GMT+0300 (+03),
      updatedAt: Fri May 20 2016 16:33:32 GMT+0300 (+03),
      _id: 573f122c7e0c94e760a6771b },{ __v: 0,
      ProjectLocation: 'Suiza',
      ProjectAmount: 888888,
      ProjectFileName: 'UploadedOn1463752504948fileOrigName13217170_1078714605505775_6819378884998619975_o.jpg',
      ProjectDetails: 'castillo en lo alto de las cumbres',
      ProjectName: 'castillo de hielo',
      ProjectOwner: '5720977ffe0697f51001c9a1',
      createdAt: Fri May 20 2016 16:55:04 GMT+0300 (+03),
      updatedAt: Fri May 20 2016 16:55:04 GMT+0300 (+03),
      _id: 573f17387e0c94e760a6771c }
```

> The log on the view show as normal content and the correct number of
>   times.

Comment: Well you have a loop that loops over all the users that the current user follows and for each of those you render the button. Did you mean to put the button outside the loop?

Answer (score 0):

`findOne()` won't return an array, so you are probably iterating over the object keys, thus having one button for each key.

You have only one follow object, so I guess you shouldn't be iterating it.

If you want more than one result to the Follow query, you should use `find` instead of `findOne`. If what you want is a single result, you should remove `for follow in listFollows`.